# LSB Encryption in BMP file for Image Stenography in Python

Tags: python, encryption, bmp

I am looking to encrypt a secret message into a BMP file in Python. I have a program that decrypts and works properly (tested using a provided image). However, the encryption is stumping me.

I've written the following code, which should be taking the least significant bits of the pixel data in a BMP file and modifying it to match the bits in the secret message.

I think there is something going on when I save the file (maybe based on the OS or Hardware) that saves the BMP differently than it would on Windows. Or I have written something incorrectly as the message is not appearing when decrypted.

Is there something I am missing here?

```
from PIL import Image
from bitstring import BitArray
import binascii
import os
import io

#Create a secret message
message = "This is my secret message"

#Convert the secret message to binary
message = ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in message)

# Open the Image of choice, Dump all binary of BMP file
with open("barbara_gray.bmp", "rb") as imageFile:
    f = imageFile.read()
    b = bytearray(f)

# BMP Header size (start of pixel data)
BMP_Header_End = 54

# Count to keep track of where we are in the secret message
count = 0

# Variable to store bit data
bit = ""

# For the total length of the secret message
for i in range(BMP_Header_End, BMP_Header_End + len(message)):
    print(count)
    # Get the LSB of the image file byte
    bit = str(b[i] & 1)

    # If the LSB is not equal to the bit of the message
    if bit != message[count]:

        # Change the byte value by 1 (effectively changing the LSB by 1)
        if b[i] == 255:
            b[i] = b[i] - 1
        else:
            b[i] = b[i] + 1

    # Move to the next character in the message
    count += 1
print(b[54:])

# Write the binary to an image file
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(b))
image.save('my_image.bmp', 'bmp')
```

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31700898/4014959 BTW, that code could be made faster by using Numpy.

Comment: I appreciate the response and I will use the resource you sent. I guess I'm more curious why the approach I've taken is not working correctly so that I can learn from my mistakes.

Comment: You should be modifying the extracted pixel data, don't try to modify the bytes in the BMP directly unless you know _exactly_ what you're doing. There are numerous variations of this ancient format, and it's not safe to fiddle with it at the byte level unless you've identified the variation exactly and you fully understand how it's structured. And even then it's easy to get it wrong. ;) But you don't need to worry about that. Just let PIL handle the messy details of the file format, and work with the pixel data it gives you.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thank you